# SharePoint Expandable Headers Solution for Pages - How to make it stay expanded in edit mode

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery

I'm using the below jQuery code I found on the net for a SharePoint page that expands an accordion. It is working well, but I'm trying to make it stay expanded when in Edit mode so it is easier for the user to maintain it. Any suggestions what would work? Thank you in advance!

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

 $(":header").css("line-height", "0%");

 $(":header").css("border-top", "5px solid transparent");

 $(":header").css("border-bottom", "5px solid transparent");

 $(":header").css("border-left", "5px solid black");

 $(":header").css("padding-left", "5px");

 $(":header").css("margin-bottom", "10px");



 $(":header").click(function(){

 $(this).nextUntil(":header").toggle();

 });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution that worked for me and can be found here:

https://info.summit7systems.com/blog/how-to-create-dynamic-accordions-in-sharepoint-pages